# Turning array of names into email addresses

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I have an array of names.  I am using GmailApp to send the email, but I am having trouble pulling the array of names and adding the domain names.  ex.

> Name= john
>   domain= @gmail.com
>   return john@gmail.com

[image]

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
var emails = []; 
var contacts = ss.getRange('A1:A7').getValues().toString();
 for(var i in contacts){
   var conc = [contacts[i] + "@gmail.com"].concat();
   emails = emails.concat(conc);
   return(emails);
 }
```

Comment: remove `toString()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apps Script has several `Array` methods of interest. Namely, [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is of use here:

```
const contacts = ss.getRange('A1:A7').getValues(); // 2D array
const emails = contacts.map(function (nameRow) { return nameRow[0] + "@gmail.com"; });
// Do stuff with the array of emails
```

If your domains are also in an array of the same shape and size, but not contiguous:

```
const contacts = ss.getRange('A1:A7').getValues();
const domains = ss.getRange('ZZ1:ZZ7').getValues();
const emails = contacts.map(function (nameRow, i) { return nameRow[0] + domains[i][0]; });
```

Comment: The top 2 lines work beautifully! Is there anyway to tell it to ignore blank lines if it encounters them?
Thanks!

Comment: @j absolutely. One of the `Array` methods available is `filter`. You would call that first, and chain the `map` call after it. I'll let you research the function and try to solve your new issue, and if you still have trouble then you should ask a new question about it.